# Choose all columns for a given ID when time is earliest in SQL query

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table like this:

```
id    time            location    price  ....
1    2022-05-01        A1          12
2    2022-04-01        A2          20
1    2022-05-04        A3          14
2    2022-04-30        B1          22
2    2022-03-01        B2          21
```

I want to run a query to choose all columns for a given ID when time is earliest, for the above table,  the result will be:

```
id    time            location    price  ....
1    2022-05-01        A1          12
2    2022-03-01        B2          21
```

Could you show me how to write this SQL query?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function to achieve this

ex:

```
select id, time, location price from (
select 
id, time, location price,
row_number() over(partition by id order by time) as rn
from table
) src
where rn = 1
```

Another option is using subquery to first calculate min time and join back to original table

ex:

```
select * 
from table a
inner join (
select id, min(time) as min_time
from table
group by id
) b on a.id = b.id and a.time = b.min_time
```